# Bug in calling self function?

Tags: lua, love2d

I wrote this code:

```
Editor = {
  x = 10,
  y = 10,
  interpreter = nil,
  cursor = nil
}

-- Some code here

function Editor:drawValues(w, h)
  for x = 0, w - 1 do
    for y = 0, h - 1 do
      local _x = self.x + x * CELL_SIZE
      local _y = self.y + y * CELL_SIZE
      love.graphics.print(self.interpreter.grid.cell[x][y], _x, _y) -- ERROR THIS!
    end
  end
end

function Editor:draw()
  local w = self.interpreter.grid.width
  local h = self.interpreter.grid.height

  Editor:drawGrid(w, h)
  Editor:drawValues(w, h)

  -- Its Works VVVVVVV
  -- for x = 0, w - 1 do
  --   for y = 0, h - 1 do
  --     local _x = self.x + x * CELL_SIZE
  --     local _y = self.y + y * CELL_SIZE
  --     local value = self.interpreter.grid.cell[x][y]
  --     love.graphics.print(value, _x, _y) -- self.interpreter.grid.cell[x][y]
  --   end
  -- end
end

return Editor
```

Function `Editor:draw` calls `Editor:drawGrid` and it works, but calling `Editor:drawValues(w, h)` throws an error:

> attempt to index field 'interpreter' (a nil value)

But! If I comment `Editor:drawValues(w, h)` and uncomment the code below, it works. Why?

Apologies for my English.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, im not expirienced in Lua, maybe i overwrite variable "Editor", but i cant understand this... It all code of editor.lua (54 lines) https://pastebin.com/08pnYurc

Comment: If `Editor` is not a singleton, you must use `self:drawValues(w, h)` instead of `Editor:drawValues(w, h)` to pass the object `self` to your method.  The class `Editor` has `interpreter = nil`, only objects have `interpreter ~= nil`